# Using variable on smarty tag name in Shopware

Tags: smarty, shopware

I'm trying to use a variable name to create new snippets, something like this:

```
{s namespace="frontend/detail/config_variant" name=$variant_group}{/s}
```

But it doesn't work, it just creates a snippet called $variant_group and I want to get the actual name. 
I have tried different combinations and none have worked so far. Can this be generated dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already mentioned in the official documentation: https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/snippets/#using-dynamic-snippets

```
{$name = "DetailDataHardness"|cat:$sArticle.attr1}
{$namespace = "frontend/detail/data"}
{$sArticle.attr1|snippet:$name:$namespace}
```

Comment: Brilliant that's exactly what I needed!